# How to fix duplicate entries in number field in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have nine number fields to calculate. I need to check for duplicate entries in these 9 number fields and if found duplicate values, change the background color of the screen to 'red'. I'm not able to find solution for the mentioned.

I have created a table with 9 nine number fields to input the numbers and calculate the sum.
I searched for code to check for duplicate values in number fields, but found code to check for duplicate values in text fields.

```html
 <html>
    <head>
    <script>
        function Sum() {
         alert("hi");
        var num1 = Number(document.getElementById("qty1").value);
        var num2 = Number(document.getElementById("qty2").value);
        var num3 = Number(document.getElementById("qty3").value);
        var num4 = Number(document.getElementById("qty4").value);
        var num5 = Number(document.getElementById("qty5").value);
        var num6 = Number(document.getElementById("qty6").value);
        var num7 = Number(document.getElementById("qty7").value);
        var num8 = Number(document.getElementById("qty8").value);
        var num9 = Number(document.getElementById("qty9").value);
        var sum=num1+num2+num3+num4+num5+num6+num7+num8+num9
        document.getElementById("answer").value = sum;
    }
    </script>

    <style>

    table>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd){
        background-color: blue;
    }

    table>tbody>tr:nth-child(even){
        background-color: green;
    }

    table>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td:nth-child(odd){
        background-color: green;
    }
    table>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td:nth-child(even){
        background-color: blue;
    }

    table>tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>td:nth-child(odd){
        background-color: blue;
    }
    table>tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>td:nth-child(even){
        background-color: green;
    }
    #sumtable th, #sumtable td{
        padding:5px;

    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <title>Sum Box</title>
    <body>
    <table align="center" id="sumtable">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
    <input type="number"  placeholder="input1"  value="input1"id="qty1"></td>
          <td>
    <input type="number"  placeholder="input2"  value="input2"  id="qty2"></td>
          <td>
    <input type="number"placeholder="input3"value="input3"id="qty3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="number"  placeholder="input4"  value="input4"  id="qty4"  ></td>
          <td><input type="number"  placeholder="input5"  value="input5"  id="qty5"  ></td>
          <td><input type="number"  placeholder="input6"  value="input6"  id="qty6"  ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="number" placeholder="input7"  value="input7"   id="qty7"  ></td>
          <td><input type="number" placeholder="input8"  value="input8"   id="qty8"  ></td>
          <td><input type="number" placeholder="input9"  value="input9"   id="qty9"  ></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
       <!-- Sum : <input type="text" name="total" id="total"/>
        <a href="javascript:sumInputs()">Sum</a>-->
        <div align="center">
        <input type="button" onclick="Sum()" name="Sum" value="Sum" id="sum">
        <input id="answer">
        </div>
         </body>
    </html>
```

The above code generates 9 input number fields in table format to enter numbers and calculate the sum

Comment: Instead of making 9 variables, make one array and add values to it. but before adding do a find on array to see if the item you are about to add already exists. You can use this to findindex. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Comment: @Sethu check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Add your numbers to an array and loop through. One possible example, see https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yZaBrb:

```
var a = new Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,2,4);

var duplicate = false;

for (i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  duplicate = false;
  for(j=0;j<a.length;j++){
    if(i != j && a[i]==a[j])  
      duplicate = true;
  } 
  if(duplicate)
    document.write('<span style="background-color:red;">')

  document.write(a[i]);

  if(duplicate)
    document.write('</span>')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two events `blur` & `keyup`. On `blur` get the value from the input and push it in an array, on `keyup` check if the array contains the same value. If the value is present in the array then add a class to the target element or remove it

```js
function Sum() {
  alert("hi");
  var num1 = Number(document.getElementById("qty1").value);
  var num2 = Number(document.getElementById("qty2").value);
  var num3 = Number(document.getElementById("qty3").value);
  var num4 = Number(document.getElementById("qty4").value);
  var num5 = Number(document.getElementById("qty5").value);
  var num6 = Number(document.getElementById("qty6").value);
  var num7 = Number(document.getElementById("qty7").value);
  var num8 = Number(document.getElementById("qty8").value);
  var num9 = Number(document.getElementById("qty9").value);
  var sum = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4 + num5 + num6 + num7 + num8 + num9
  document.getElementById("answer").value = sum;
}

let sumArray = []

document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]').forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
    sumArray.push(e.target.value)
  })

  item.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    if (sumArray.indexOf(e.target.value) !== -1) {
      e.target.parentNode.classList.add('error')
    } else if (e.target.parentNode.classList.contains('error')) {
      e.target.parentNode.classList.remove('error')
    }
  })
})
```

```css
table>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}

table>tbody>tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: green;
}

table>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: green;
}

table>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: blue;
}

table>tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}

table>tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>td:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: green;
}

#sumtable th,
#sumtable td {
  padding: 5px;
}

.error {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<title>Sum Box</title>

<body>
  <table align="center" id="sumtable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="number" placeholder="input1" value="input1" id="qty1"></td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" placeholder="input2" value="input2" id="qty2"></td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" placeholder="input3" value="input3" id="qty3"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="number" placeholder="input4" value="input4" id="qty4"></td>
        <td><input type="number" placeholder="input5" value="input5" id="qty5"></td>
        <td><input type="number" placeholder="input6" value="input6" id="qty6"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="number" placeholder="input7" value="input7" id="qty7"></td>
        <td><input type="number" placeholder="input8" value="input8" id="qty8"></td>
        <td><input type="number" placeholder="input9" value="input9" id="qty9"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- Sum : <input type="text" name="total" id="total"/>
    <a href="javascript:sumInputs()">Sum</a>-->
  <div align="center">
    <input type="button" onclick="Sum()" name="Sum" value="Sum" id="sum">
    <input id="answer">
  </div>
```

Comment: Not getting same result when I run in my system

Comment: could you please share the code . I'm not getting the same when I run in my system.

Answer (score 0):

its pretty simple just put same class in input field and loop through it like

In Html ,

```
  <td>
    <input type="number" class="checkSame"  placeholder="input1"  value="input1"id="qty1"></td>
          <td>
    <input type="number" class="checkSame" placeholder="input2"  value="input2"  id="qty2"></td>
          <td>
    <input type="number" class="checkSame" placeholder="input3"value="input3"id="qty3"></td>
```

then in javascript ,

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("checkSame");
var temp;
var count = 1;
for(var i = 0; i < inputs .length; i++)
{
   temp = document.getElementsByClassName("checkSame")[i].value;
   if(temp == document.getElementsByClassName("checkSame")[count++].value)
   {
       //change your background color here
       break;
   }
}
```

i think it works.

Comment: How to do the same using event handling in Javascript without button clicking

Comment: on which event you want to do

Comment: 9 input fields. 
Enter numbers to the input field. 
Alternatively, change the background color of the input field to green and blue for each input 
When duplicate numbers found, the whole background need becomes red
Need to display a sum of all inputs. It should be calculated for each input

Comment: i didn't understand please describe what you need clearly or ask another question or start personal chat.

Comment: while inputting values from one input field to another if there's duplication of value. Highlight the input box with red color and sum should be generated automatically without button click using event handling in javascript

Comment: as you describe i think you should use onchange event on every input.

Comment: how to do that?@Rahul Dudharejiya

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you to find duplicate fields

```js
function Sum() {
  alert("hi");
  let arr = [];
  let sum;
  let duplicate = false;
  for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    let num = Number(document.getElementById(`qty${i}`).value);
    let indexOfDuplicateNum = arr.indexOf(num);
    if (indexOfDuplicateNum > -1){
        duplicate = true;
       alert('Duplicate value found!');
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background = 'red';
  document.getElementById(`qty${i}`).classList.add('duplicate-error');
  document.getElementById(`qty${indexOfDuplicateNum+1}`).classList.add('duplicate-error');
    break;
    } else{
    //remove error class if value is not duplicate
    document.getElementById(`qty${i}`).classList.remove('duplicate-error');
     arr.push(num); 
     sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => a+b, 0);
    }
  }
  
  if (!duplicate) {
    document.getElementById('answer').value = sum;
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background = 'white';
  }
  }
```

```css
.duplicate-error {
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
    table>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd){
        background-color: blue;
    }

    table>tbody>tr:nth-child(even){
        background-color: green;
    }

    table>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td:nth-child(odd){
        background-color: green;
    }
    table>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td:nth-child(even){
        background-color: blue;
    }

    table>tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>td:nth-child(odd){
        background-color: blue;
    }
    table>tbody>tr:nth-child(even)>td:nth-child(even){
        background-color: green;
    }
    #sumtable th, #sumtable td{
        padding:5px;

    }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Sum Calculator</title>
    </head>
    <title>Sum Box</title>
    <body>
    <table align="center" id="sumtable">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
    <input type="number"  placeholder="input1"  value="input1"id="qty1"></td>
          <td>
    <input type="number"  placeholder="input2"  value="input2"  id="qty2"></td>
          <td>
    <input type="number"placeholder="input3"value="input3"id="qty3"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="number"  placeholder="input4"  value="input4"  id="qty4"  ></td>
          <td><input type="number"  placeholder="input5"  value="input5"  id="qty5"  ></td>
          <td><input type="number"  placeholder="input6"  value="input6"  id="qty6"  ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="number" placeholder="input7"  value="input7"   id="qty7"  ></td>
          <td><input type="number" placeholder="input8"  value="input8"   id="qty8"  ></td>
          <td><input type="number" placeholder="input9"  value="input9"   id="qty9"  ></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
       <!-- Sum : <input type="text" name="total" id="total"/>
        <a href="javascript:sumInputs()">Sum</a>-->
        <div align="center">
        <input type="button" onclick="Sum()" name="Sum" value="Sum" id="sum">
        <input id="answer">
        </div>
         </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks Niraj Kaushal, but this code of yours doesn't change the background color to red if duplicate entries are found.

Comment: how to do the same using event handling in javascript?